# Two Player Game Simulation: Creating lists from a dataset

Tags: r, vector, simulation, probability, utility

I'm very new to R and am coding a two player game where the first player knows the goal of the game and the second does not, yet they are helping.

I'm attempting to code for the first player and I want to create code that picks a move based on if it helps move the goal of the game forward.

Goal of the game::: to move all red colored pieces to the second section (section B).

Values for the vector::
-If the move helps the game forward it would have the value 1

-If it doesn't (but doesn't obstruct the goal like moving to an empty space) it would be 0

-If it obstructs the goal (like moving on top of a red piece) it would equal -1

I am looking to create code that loops through a data set and generates a utility vector for each piece on the top of the column based on the goal and the vector values described above.

Anyway, here's some sample code:

```
#for reference of what the numbers mean:
red <- 2
non.red <- 1
empty <- 0

#code for the initial game board 
One<- c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,0,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,0)
Two <- c(1,1,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,1,0)
Three <-c(2,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0)
Four <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Five <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Board.game.act <- rbind.data.frame(Five, Four, Three, Two, One)

colnames(Board.game.act) <- c("1A", "2A", "3A", "4B", "5B", "6B", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10D", "11D", "12D", "13E", "14E", "15E", "16F", "17F", "18F")

#goal is to move all blues to columns 4-6 or section "B"
#only top of the columns can be moved 
#code output for desired utility vector would something like:

red.1 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
non.2 <- c(-1,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0)
red.3 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
red.4 <-  c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
non.5 <- c(-1,0,-1,-1,0,-1,-1, 0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0)
non.6 <- c(-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0)
non.7 <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
red.8 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
red.10 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
non.11 <- c(-1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0)
non.12 <- c(-1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1, 0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0)
red.13 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
red.14 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
red.15 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
non.16 <- c(-1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0)
non.17 <- c(-1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0)

#I created the above utility vectors manually based on the first players possible first moves
```

If you could give me pointers as how to have my code generate these vectors by itself, I would appreciate it!

Thanks again!

Comment: Not an answer but 1) Your df has 5 columns but the `colnames` vector has length 18; 2) if you define `blue`, why use a constant `2` in the `which`?

Comment: Hi Rui, thank you for your comment. 1.) If I run it, it does give me 18 columns that I am able to name in the line below it. Each vector shows up as a row when binded. 2.) I defined blue to make it clear what pieces I was moving and thought to keep numbers in the matrix to make it simple.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you for your instruction. I have edited the question to have one component and an example.